# Find the number of conjugate classes for $GL(3,\mathbb{F})$ where $|\mathbb{F}|=7$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to find the number of all conjugate classes for $GL(3,\mathbb{F})$ where $|\mathbb{F}|=7$ using the number of possible rational canonical form matrix possible. What is the solution for this question?

Comment: What's going wrong with the approach you outlined?  It's hard to help you if you don't say what your difficulty is.

Comment: well my difficult is trying to specify all the options really, I dont know really how to approach this methodically.

Comment: Do you know what the rational canonical form looks like?  Can you write down what the general form is, before trying to do any counting?

Comment: Hint: think of "rational canonical form" really as being about "elementary divisors", in $\mathbb F_7[x]$. That is, a sequence of monic polynomials $d_1, d_2, ...$ so that $d_i|d_{i+1}$ and the sum of the degrees is $3$.